# Forms of ${\rm SL}(2)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, algebraic-number-theory, galois-cohomology

I know all real forms of ${\rm SL}(2,{\Bbb C}$).  They are ${\rm SL}(2,{\Bbb R})$ and ${\rm SU}(2)$.
Moreover, ${\rm SL}(2,{\Bbb R})$ is isomorphic to ${\rm SU}(1,1)$. Thus I can say that  all real forms of ${\rm SL}(2,{\Bbb C})$
are of the form  ${\rm SU}(2,F_\lambda)$, where $F_\lambda$ is the diagonal Hermitian form on ${\Bbb C}^2$
with matrix  ${\rm diag}(1,\lambda)$,   $\lambda$ taking the values 1 and $-1$.

> **Question.** Is it true that any ${\Bbb Q}$-form of ${\rm SL}(2,{\Bbb C})$ is isomorphic to ${\rm SU}(2,F_{K,\lambda})$,
> where $F_{K,\lambda}$ is the diagonal Hermitian form on $K^2$ for some quadratic extension $K/{\Bbb Q}$ with matrix  ${\rm diag}(1,\lambda)$,
> for some $\lambda\in {\Bbb Q}^\times$ ?

Comment: What about the kernel of the reduced norm on the multiplicative group of a quaternion algebra?

Comment: @JasonStarr: Could you please kindly add details? What quaternion algebra do you mean?

Comment: A quaternion algebra is a form of the algebra of $2\times 2$ matrices. The multiplicative group of the quaternion algebra is a form of $GL(2)$. Inside it is a form of $SL(2)$. I believe that your Hermitian form examples can be described in these terms, and vice versa; and maybe this in fact gives all the forms of $SL(2)$.

Comment: Probably you are correct.  I do not have my copy of “Galois cohomology” with me.  Serre discusses the forms of SL_2 near the beginning of Part II of the book.

Comment: Dear @JasonStarr and Tom, I do understand all what you wrote. The question is how I can construct a quaternion algebra from a Hermitian form and vice versa. I don't think that this is explained in Serre's book...

Comment: The quaternion algebra interpretation gives a classification up to isomorphism. The hermitian fact follows, and to complete the picture, one has to check for which $(K_1,\lambda_1)$, $(K_2,\lambda_2)$, the two corresponding $\mathrm{SU}_2$ groups are $K$-isomorphic (no reason to stick to $K=\mathbf{Q}$).

Comment: @YCor: Please kindly add details!

Comment: I don't know to which extent Serre's proof can be made constructive. A constructive approach is to consider the adjoint representation, and then identify $G/Z(G)$ to $\mathrm{SO}$ of some explicit 3-dim quadratic form (the Killing form). I don't know if how easy it is to lift this to a Hermitian description of $G$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\PGL{PGL}\DeclareMathOperator\Br{Br}\DeclareMathOperator\U{U}\DeclareMathOperator\disc{disc}\DeclareMathOperator\Nm{Nm}\DeclareMathOperator\diag{diag}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$The general theory tells us that forms of a reductive group $G$ are classified by $H^1$ of the automorphism group, which is a semidirect product $(\text{root datum automorphisms}) \ltimes (\text{inner automorphisms})$. For $\SL_2 / k$ the root datum has no automorphisms, so the classifying object is $H^1(k, \PGL_2(\overline{k})) \cong H^2(k, \smash{\overline{k}}^\times)[2] = \Br(k)[2]$. Hence, by standard results on the Brauer group, a form of $\SL_2$ over a number field is uniquely determined by the set of places at which it's locally non-split, and the only constraint on this set is that it must have even size.

Now, let's look at unitary groups $\U(V)$ over local fields. If $k$ is local and $K$ is a degree 2 étale ring extension of $k$, then $K$ is either $k \oplus k$ or a field extension. In the former case, any Hermitian space wrt $K/k$ is obviously split. In the latter case, the isomorphism class of $V$ is uniquely determined by the discriminant $\disc(V) \in k^\times / \Nm(K^\times)$. For your example, with matrix $\diag(1, \lambda)$, the discriminant is $-\lambda$. When $V$ is split, then one computes that $\SU(V) \cong \SL(2)$, as in the familiar argument for $k = \mathbf{R}$ (of course $\U(V)$ is *not* $\GL(2)$ unless $K = k \oplus k$!)

Conversely: it's non-obvious, but true, that if $V$ is non-split then $\SU(V)$ is also non-split. If it were split, then the Borel subgroup of $G$ would have to have a fixed point in $\mathbf{P}(V)$ by the Borel–Morozov theorem; and the restriction of the Hermitian form to this line has to be zero, hence $V$ is split.

Going back to the global case, if $K = k(\sqrt{\alpha})$, and $\beta = -\lambda$, we have shown that $\SU(F_{K,\lambda})$ is split locally at $v$ if and only if $(\alpha, \beta)_{k_v} = 1$, where $(-, -)_{k_v}$ is the Hilbert symbol. In other words, $\SU(F_{K,\lambda})$ is split locally at $v$ if and only if the quaternion algebra $D = (\alpha, \beta)_k$ splits there. So $\SU(F_{K,\lambda})$ is isomorphic to $(D^\times)^{\Nm = 1}$.

Since every quaternion algebra is $(\alpha,\beta)_{k}$ for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we conclude **the answer to the question is "Yes: if $k$ is a number field, every $\overline{k}/k$-form of $\SL_2 / k$ is isomorphic to such an $\SU(2, F_{K, \lambda})$ for some quadratic extension $K/k$ and $\lambda \in k^\times$".**

[PS: With a little more work, one should be able to write down explicitly an isomorphism from $\SU(F_{k(\sqrt{\alpha}),\lambda})$ to the norm 1 elements of $D^\times$ where $D = (\alpha, -\lambda)_k$, using the fact that $D$ is naturally a 2-dim'l vector space over $k(\sqrt{\alpha})$. But it's a Sunday morning so I'm going to be lazy and not do the exercise.]

Comment: Small unimportant correction: it is not true that the root datum of $SL_n$ has no non-trivial automorphisms if $n>2$: in that case the Dynkin diagram has a unique nontrivial involution as a symmetry.

Comment: Aargh, of course you are correct, for $n > 2$ there is a quasi-split outer form. I will edit to make the statement for $n = 2$ only.

Comment: What are restrictions on $k$ to make the Galois cohomology argument work? It works for $k$ perfect, and probably in more cases here? I guess that the result itself (at least: $k$-forms of $\mathrm{SL}_2\leftrightarrow$ (quaternion algebras over $k$) holds for arbitrary fields?

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Comment: @YCor: Yes, $k$-forms of ${\rm  SL}_2$ $\leftrightarrow$  (quaternion algebras over $k$) holds for arbitrary fields. See Serre, Galois Cohomology, Section III.1.4.